# How to keep track of certain screens opened?

Tags: ios

Working with a QR scanner for IOS. Generated my own unique QR codes to match each "screen".
Below is the code snippet used to list all the screens the QR Scanner finds.That woks fine and does scan the QR Code and opens the corresponding screen.

What I need now is to keep track of a certain screen and how many times it's scanned and displayed so that if it is displayed more than say 3 times a different screen will appear.

The idea is that if the same QR Code is scanned more than 3 times a warning screen will appear.
Any ideas how to do this?

```
//loop through every screen in the applications list of screens
    for(int i = 0; i < [[appDelegate.rootApp screens] count]; i++){
        BT_item *thisScreen = [[appDelegate.rootApp screens] objectAtIndex:i];
      //  [BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"thisScreen:%@", thisScreen.itemId]];

        if ([thisScreen.itemId isEqualToString:result] ) {
            [self handleTapToLoadScreen:thisScreen theMenuItemData:nil];
            return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [NSCountedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/index.html) to track how many times each code was scanned. NSCountedSet will hold an unordered set of objects, as well as how many times they've been added to the set

So for example, the following:

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init];
NSArray *codes = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"a", @"b", @"a", @"a"];

for (NSString *code in codes) {
    [countedSet addObject:code];

    if ([countedSet countForObject:code] > 3) {
        NSLog(@"more than 3");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"3 or less");
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",countedSet);
```

Outputs

> 3 or less
>
> 3 or less
>
> 3 or less
>
> 3 or less
>
> 3 or less
>
> 3 or less
>
> 3 or less
>
> more than 3
>
> (d [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/index.html), b [2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/NSCoding), c [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/index.html), a [4])

And since NSCountedSet is [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/NSCoding) compliant, it's easy to serialize your set object and store it to persist between launches.

Comment: K Thanks! I'm not great with the logic part but still trying to learn. I'll tinker a bit. hopefully i can ask for more help if needed:)

Comment: @IanJames That's okay. The usage of this class should be fairly straight forward as long as you make sure that you do all your comparison on the same instance of NSCountedSet. And sorry about that original answer, I guess I'm stuck in Swift gear.

Comment: So would I use "result" for the countedset? Trouble getting started. More of a hack at this level. I really appreciate the help

Comment: It's actually going to be for just one screen that needs to be kept track of then if it is used more than 3 times it shows a different screen. all other codes can be scanned however many times.            BT_item *QRcode1 = [appDelegate.rootApp getScreenDataByItemId:@"2402E58B73513EFEE08F5DE"];

Comment: BT_item *countScreenOne = [appDelegate.rootApp getScreenDataByItemId:@"2402E58B73513EFEE08F5DE"];
        if (thisScreen == countScreenOne ) {
            
            NSArray *countQR = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:countScreenOne, nil];
            NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:countQR];
            
            for (id item in set)
            {
                NSLog(@"countQR=%@, Count=%lu", item, (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]);
            }

        }

Comment: The above code gets me the screen count as 1. How do i store it so it will eventually count to 3? It resets when leaving screen and coming back. thanks!!